# AutoLayout issue?

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I have made simple screen,

1. One ImageView
2. One Label
3. One Button

It looks like in iPhone 4 inch simulator

[image]

But when I run it on iPhone 3.5, its settings label goes up.

I can't understand which parameter will be set to see desired output.

Question: How can I properly use AutoLayout?

[image]

Comment: set constraints of uilabel

Comment: Constrains of UIlabel are set, But No use. I tried you answer too. 
Actually I am lacking the real calculations, can you find me any good tutorial to read on this purpose.

Comment: if possible link your sample project

Comment: http://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/jack-cox/ios-7-tutorial-series-auto-layout-xcode-5

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: The constraint at the bottom of the list above, the vertical spacing one of 517 - what views is this between? This is almost definitely the one causing the problem, can it be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

set constraints properly of your label like

[image]

Comment: It joinged the button with Label in iphone4 inch and in 3.5inch, it places button before label and label vanished.

Comment: post your widgets hierarchy

Comment: Hierarchy of Views are visible in above Question dear, which hierarchy you want other than that?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, just follow the steps and you should be fine.

Step 1: Make sure that your size class is "wCompact hRegular" and then add your label, button and image view.

[image]

Step 2: Constrains for the label.

[image]

Step 3: Constrains for the button

[image]

Step 4: Constrains for the image view assuming that you want your image view to cover almost the entrée screen after the label and button.

[image]

Done!

I tested in both iPhone 4s(same as iPhone 4) and iPhone 5s. It looks fine to me.

[image]

[image]